# Andorid Studio: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Создал Drawer_layout, задал разметку, при попытке запустить приложение - крашит с ошибкой Error inflating class . Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_people_24"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_contacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="@string/drawer_el_padding"
            android:gravity="center|start">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_list_bulleted_24"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@string/drawer_contact_list"
                android:textSize="@string/drawer_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_favorite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="@string/drawer_el_padding"
            android:gravity="center|start">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/drawer_favorite"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="@string/drawer_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@string/drawer_el_padding"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@string/drawer_settings"
                android:textSize="@string/drawer_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Лог ошибки:

```
2022-03-28 18:27:09.900 22367-22367/com.devshev.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.devshev.contacts, PID: 22367
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.devshev.contacts/com.devshev.contacts.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.devshev.contacts:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #38 in com.devshev.contacts:layout/drawer_layout: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.devshev.contacts:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #38 in com.devshev.contacts:layout/drawer_layout: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.devshev.contacts:layout/drawer_layout: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.devshev.contacts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
2022-03-28 18:27:09.902 22367-22367/com.devshev.contacts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 14 to dimension: type=0x3
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:786)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5257)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:254)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:250)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:246)
            ... 37 more
```

Comment: при попытке запустить что? разметку?

Comment: Покажите полный лог ошибки - без него сложно вам помочь

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил лог

Comment: @Эникейщик, всё приложение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по логу у вас проблема может быть в этой строке:

> android:padding="@string/drawer_el_padding

Вы используете строку вместо указания размера. Замените это на что-то типа 16dp

Comment: Спасибо большое, в упор не замечал, что в логе пишется номер строки) Открыли мне глаза